# How to parse "2021-01-19T16:20:04+0000" as time.Time

Tags: go, time

I've tried the following format which should catch the `+0000` timezone offset as I read https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants:

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", "2021-01-19T16:20:04+0000")
```

But that looks rather strange when the result ist printed (no error):

```
2021-01-19 16:47:00 +0000 +0000
```

**UPDATE**

Running https://play.golang.org/p/wHBYz7iKnLT locally (OSX 11.1) gives the strange result:

```
❯ gor time.go 
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000 +0000 <nil>
```

Comment: I copied & pasted your sample string and format string and it works as expected in playground, if it's not working for you, please show the full code to reproduce the issue. https://play.golang.org/p/wHBYz7iKnLT

Comment: You call it "strange" twice - what's strange about it exactly?

Comment: It looked to me like double timezone, but @icza explained it very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the "default" formatting, e.g. when printed like `fmt.Println(ts)`, which is the result of [`Time.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String). Quoting from `Time.String()`:

> String returns the time formatted using the format string
>
> ```
> "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
> ```

As you can see, it contains **the zone offset and the zone name** in the end.

Also note that you used [`time.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) which documents that:

> In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.
>
> When parsing a time with a zone offset like -0700, if the offset corresponds to a time zone used by the current location (Local), then Parse uses that location and zone in the returned time. Otherwise it records the time as being in a fabricated location with time fixed at the given zone offset.

Since on the Go Playground the local time is set to `UTC` whose offset matches the offset of the time you parse, that zone will be used, so printing it on the Go Playground you'll see `UTC`.

When you parse it locally (on your computer) and the local time zone is not UTC or another zone that has 0 offset, as per the doc, that location is recorded as a fabricated location with the name having the offset.

So when you parse and print that time locally, since the default format includes both the zone offset and the zone name, and since both are `+0000`, you'll see `+0000` printed twice.

Worry not, the parsed time is of course correct:

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", "2021-01-19T16:20:04+0000")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(ts)

fmt.Println(ts.Format("2006-01-02 16:04:05 -0700"))
fmt.Println(ts.Format("2006-01-02 16:04:05 MST"))
```

This outputs on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LwtxTUYdlXZ):

```
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000 UTC
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000
2021-01-19 16:20:04 UTC
```

Locally (having `CET` zone) it outputs:

```
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000 +0000
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +0000
```

Note that if you'd parse a time with a different zone offset (not being 0), you'll see the same on the Go Playground too. For example:

```
ts, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700", "2021-01-19T16:20:04+1100")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(ts)

fmt.Println(ts.Format("2006-01-02 16:04:05 -0700"))
fmt.Println(ts.Format("2006-01-02 16:04:05 MST"))
```

This outputs both on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i4JCP8t2I8w) and locally for me (with `CET` zone):

```
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +1100 +1100
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +1100
2021-01-19 16:20:04 +1100
```